# Teams adaptive cards, disabling or hiding fields after submit

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Saying I have the following very simple adaptive card template:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Feedback",
            "id": "feedback_text"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Submit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do one of the following:

- When a user submit feedback, we remove submit button (set isVisible to false perhaps)
- When a user submit feedback, we disable submit button

What I'm seeking is the ability for a user to submit a feedback one time only. I'm using .NET Bot framework SDK as a backend for my bot.

But is this doable from the adaptive card side? By some configuration or data approach?

And if not, is it even doable from the backend side somehow?

I've searched a lot of such scenarios here, but couldn't find any appropriate answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following documentation for the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet#update-messages

You can replace the adaptive card content using below syntax:

```css
var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
activity.Id = turnContext.Activity.ReplyToId;
await turnContext.UpdateActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Okay, so saying I'm working with the following:
`protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

How should I get the `card` entity mentioned above?? From the context or what?

Comment: `card` is a data structure representing the new card you wish to replace the old card with.  In .NET, this could be a `Dictionary` structured like the JSON versions of the adaptive cards you see in the docs.